# Markup to c# & SQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, code-generation

I was wondering if there was a simple markup that would generate my C# classes for me along with (My)SQL create table. Preferably one that supports indexes and FK

Comment: The Entity Framework kinda does this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an entity model with the designer. Afterwards you can enable sql tracing/or export the creation script via your favorite database tool. Just look for "LINQ to SQL Classes" when adding a new file to the project. The file extension is dbml.

Comment: entity seems like a lot of work. I think i'll just write the sql create table by hand. Its only 8tables anyways

Comment: @acidzombie24 Using the entity designer, you can generate your tables in a visual designer (with lines and all that) and it will create objects for you to interact with. The objects take care of their own querying and stuff. There's also a way to do it the other way around (create the tables from your model) but I never tried it out.

Comment: The designer can also import a schema from an existing database as well.  We use it with Oracle, works pretty well.

Comment: It is also possible to design that dynamically! So you don't need to have fixed tables. If you want to get further ones, you can load them with a new assembly with a little workaround :)

Answer (score 2):

We have used [CodeSmith](http://www.codesmithtools.com) to do this for a long time. You can generate classes from existing SQL tables and the scripting capability of the tool allows you to fine tune the output to be exactly what you want. For example, all of our business classes inherit from the same base class, so we just modified the script to include this base class in the generated output.